# How to groupby certain column in a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe where I have different genes, drugs ID's and citations.  I essentially need the same gene to be merged with the same drug but include both citations for that drug if it is to occur.  For example below:
pharmacogenomic

```
      Gene                          Drug                     ID     Cite
1  MAD1L1                       Lithium[17]           34718328     [17]
2    OAS1                       Lithium[17]           34718328     [17]
3    OAS1                       Lithium[7]            27401222      [7]
```

MAD1L1 has lithium and citation 17, but OAS1 has lithium and citation 17 and 7.  I would like to concat the table into something similar to below:

```
      Gene                          Drug                     ID     Cite
1  MAD1L1                       Lithium[17]           34718328     [17]
2    OAS1                       Lithium[17][7]        34718328     [17]
```

OAS1 has lithium ,but both citation are next to eachother, and MAD1L1 is unchanged as it does not share the same citation for lithium as OAS1.

Comment: What about the Cite column for Gene OSA1? Shouldn't this also contain the citations next to each other?

Comment: @VishnuNadhan I suppose it can, as I really only care about the drug and gene column, but those two citation have different ID's meaning they have different citation pertaining to them.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
#use cite to group together the citations
df['cite2']=df.groupby('Gene')['Cite'].transform('sum')

#group by gene, and take the first result for each gene
df2=df.groupby('Gene').first()

#split the citation from the Drug name and append the cite2 (created above)
df2['Drug']=df2['Drug'].str.split('[', expand=True)[0] + df2['cite2']

# drop the temporary cite2 columns
df2.drop(columns='cite2', inplace=True)
df2.reset_index()
```

```
    Gene    Drug    ID  Cite
0   MAD1L1  Lithium[17]     34718328    [17]
1   OAS1    Lithium[17][7]  34718328    [17]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the citation from "Drug", then `groupby.agg`, either as 'first' or to `join` the strings. Then add back the citations:

```
out = (df
 .assign(Drug=df['Drug'].str.extract(r'(^[^\[\]]+)', expand=False))
 .groupby(['Gene', 'Drug'], as_index=False)
 .agg({'ID': 'first', 'Cite': ''.join})
 .assign(Drug=lambda d: d['Drug']+d['Cite'])
)
```

Output:

```
     Gene            Drug        ID     Cite
0  MAD1L1     Lithium[17]  34718328     [17]
1    OAS1  Lithium[17][7]  34718328  [17][7]
```